# Why there is no Page scope in JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee

My questions says it all..
We have different type of scopes in JSF but why not Page scope?
Thank you

Comment: Those kind of questions are a little off-topic. If your question was: `I need to use Page scope in JSF because I am trying to do XXX` (where you would replace `XXX` with a precise explanation of what you are trying to do and why you need such feature) then your question would have been better.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov we have page scope in JSP,then why n't in JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page scope as defined in [JavaServer Pages 2.2](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245):

> Objects with `page` scope are accessible only within the page where they
>   are created. All references to such an object shall be released after
>   the response is sent back to the client from the JSP page or the
>   request is forwarded somewhere else. References to objects with page
>   scope are stored in the `pageContext` object.

Page scope as defined by JSPs is not an appropriate scope to use in JSF. There is no reason for the view to be creating objects directly. If a managed bean were defined in page scope it could not be resolved by any page action as the JSP would not be invoked until the render response phase of the [JSF request lifecycle](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/).

In JSF, the JSP merely serves as the View Definition Language; it performs no business logic.

Answer (score 1):

What should the page Page scope mean?In JSF 2.0 you have [ViewScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367147/use-of-viewscoped-in-jsf-2-0) which is used when you are triggering some actions on the same page and you want to hold your data during this process. If this is not enough for you, IceFaces offers you a custom [WindowScope](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ice/window+scope) which extends ViewScope and it can survive page refresh.

Comment: Viewscope is same as page scope?

Comment: Not exactly, it depends on your needs. JSF is really different from JSP, see McDowells answer, he explains it well.