# Clear object on ViewScope destroy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jsf-2

Well, I changed my application FlushMode from AUTO to COMMIT, because i don't want to update or insert new objects from dirty-check hibernate.

**I will try explain my problem with a scenario:** 
I have a ManagedBean (CustomerMB) linked with a XHTML (customer.xhtml) page, this ManagedBean is "ViewScoped" and have a object called "bean" (Customer.class type).

User starts to change information about Customer (like name, age, address and others), and this values are set into "bean" object. But for some unknown reason, user decide to click "F5" (refresh browser) and ViewScoped is destroyed and another is created (i think so).

In this moment i expect that all informations about "Customer" was lost (this is correct for me) and user must start again the changes of this Customer. But the opposite happens, the "bean" object continue with all information in cache, and if i change my XHTML page to another managedBean the "bean" object also continue in cache and i don't want this.

I tried to set `"bean = null"` in my ManagedBean but when i do a `"SELECT * FROM Customer c WHERE c.id = :id"` the "customer" object is returned with new value (typed by user)  and not equal Database as i expected, i don't know why.

Comment: You have wrong design: update data in object from DB in xhtml is not good practice. Use form and update data in DB from form bean on submit action.

Comment: `if i change my XHTML page to another managedBean the "bean" object also continue in cache`. Well, that's an unproper use of `@ViewScoped`. I always bind my views to an only `@ManagedBean`, so when user performs navigation from one view to another, a new `@ViewScoped` bean is intantiated for the destination view. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367147/use-of-viewscoped-in-jsf-2-0