# JSF how to store, with Controller, in session without persist in DB

Tags: java, jsf, session, controller

I'm trying to make a page where the user can insert one or more Providers, check all the Providers inserted, then confirm. ONLY when the user confirms, all the Providers inserted will be stored in my Database.
How can I do that? It seems that if I use my ManagedBean Controller, with List where I will store the Providers, I get a strange error

```
HTTP Status 500 -
root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
it.myProject.model.Provider.equals(Provider.java:71)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.SelectItemsIterator.next(SelectItemsIterator.java:275)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.SelectItemsIterator.next(SelectItemsIterator.java:49)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.RendererUtils.internalGetSelectItemList(RendererUtils.java:800)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.RendererUtils.getSelectItemList(RendererUtils.java:764)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlSelectableRendererBase.internalRenderSelect(HtmlSelectableRendererBase.java:74)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlMenuRendererBase.renderMenu(HtmlMenuRendererBase.java:91)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlMenuRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlMenuRendererBase.java:76)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:665)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:545)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.actuallyRenderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:364)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:201)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
```

here's the code of my ProviderController

```
@ManagedBean
public class ProviderController{
private Long id;
private String vat;
private String address;
private List<Product> products;
private Provider provider;
private List<Provider> providers;

public ProviderController() {
this.products= new LinkedList<>();
this.providers= new LinkedList<>();
}
//adds the Provider in the c:forEach of the view newProvider.jsp
public String addProvider() {
    this.provider= new Provider(vat, address, products);
    this.providers.add(this.provider);
    return "newProvider";
}
```

-I omitted the facade because I have nothing to store in this case, I just want to add the provider in the list and THEN, with another method, add all the providers of the list in my db

-Provider is a Model that uses the annotation @Entity, so my doubt is that I can't use Provider if I don't use the EntityManager

If I'm right, what can I do to store simply in session my providers? I have to create another class Provider? I have to create another ProviderController?

Thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: Try to use conversational scope. When the controller starts call Conversation.begin() to start the scope. Then each request will create a new Provider. When you are done you end the conversational scope with Conversation.end() and store the Providers in db. Search internet to read for conversational scope.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping apart from your hypothetical persistence layer, you can store the information in the session. However, you have to differ between the information that belongs to the session and the one that does to the current view.

For your case, I think you want to have the stored providers as a session variable, while the information you send in the form when adding a new one should be in view scope. That way you divide the logic of the application in a proper way. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367147/use-of-viewscoped-in-jsf-2-0) you've got more information about the view scope, introduced in JSF 2.

As you're already in JSF 2, you could choose between JSP and Facelets for your view technology. If it's a new project, I encourage you to go with facelets, as it is the standard for JSF 2:

**ProviderController.java**

```
/*
* Manages providers in the session
*/
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ProviderController{

    private List<Provider> providers;
    private List<Product> products;

    public ProviderController() {
        this.products= new LinkedList<>();
        this.providers= new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public List<Provider> getProviders(){
        return providers;
    }

}
```

**providers.xhtml**

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head />

<h:body>

<!-- Display all the providers from the session -->
    <ul>
        <ui:repeat value="#{providerController.providers}" var="provider">
            <li>#{provider.vat}-#{provider.address}</li>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>

</h:body>

</html>
```

**ProviderAdd.java**

```
/*
* Manages the view to add a new provider
*/
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProviderAdd{

    private Long id;
    private String vat;
    private String address;

    //Injects the session scoped bean
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{providerController}")
    private ProviderController providerController;

    //Getter and setters


    //Adds a new provider to the session and returns to the provider list
    public String addProvider() {
        this.provider= new Provider(this.vat, this.address, this.products);
        providerController.getProviders.add(this.provider);
        return "providers";
    }

}
```

**addProvider.xhtml**

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head />

<h:body>

    <h2>VAT:</h2><h:inputText value="#{providerAdd.vat}" />
    <h2>Address:</h2><h:inputText value="#{providerAdd.address}" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{providerAdd.addProvider}" value="Add provider" />

</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try these next days your answer!