# How to keep tree selection on a @ViewScoped bean when page is refreshed?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, page-refresh, view-scope

I have a JSF page with a primefaces tree and I store the actual selection in a @ViewScoped bean. If the user refresh the page (or I trigger a refresh of the page) the selection is lost. I don't want to make the bean @SessionScoped, how can I keep the tree selection?

Comment: read this very interesting post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367147/use-of-viewscoped-in-jsf-2-0

Comment: my question is why you dont want to use `@SessionScoped` ?!?

Comment: Try using the codi @ViewAccessScoped

Comment: @Yagami Light I have other problems if I use SessionScoped bean (the user case is a little more complex, but if I can solve this problem I think I don't need to use SessionScoped)

Comment: @Kukeltje ViewAccessScoped it's non-standard JSF....

Comment: Neither is PrimeFaces

Answer (score 0):

One have either to store the selection in a SessionScoped Bean or to store the selection in a class not managed by JSF but accessed through a SessionScoped Bean.

Comment: There is thing called @ViewAccessScoped in deltaspike. Perfect for this job. And effectively hidden from you, it does what you mention last. Use a map in a sessionscoped bean and manipulate that.