# Am working on ViewScoped annotation in jsf but am not getting correct output

Tags: jsf-2, view-scope

I am working on @ViewScoped annotation in JSF2.0. Below is the code what I had written. It is not working as I expected. Please review it and let me know if any changes are required to get the exact output that what am thinking of.

Here is my Controller SearchController.java

```
package com.s2tech.jsfapp.controllers;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import com.s2tech.jsfapp.helper.SearchHelper;
import com.s2tech.jsfapp.managedbean.SearchManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name ="searchController")
@ViewScoped
public class SearchController  implements Serializable{
    public SearchController(){

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     SearchHelper searchHelper;

    private List<SearchManagedBean> employeeList=new ArrayList<SearchManagedBean>();

    public List<SearchManagedBean> getEmployeeList() {
        return employeeList;
    }

    public void setEmployeeList(List<SearchManagedBean> employeeList) {
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }


    public void  getEmployee(SearchManagedBean searchManagedBean) {
       searchHelper=new SearchHelper();

         employeeList = searchHelper.getEmployee(searchManagedBean);

         //return "search.xhtml";

    //return Constants.searchPage;

    //   return null;
            }
```

Below is my view search.xhtml

```
<h:body style="background-color:skyblue;">
<ui:include src="mainMenu.xhtml"></ui:include>
<h:form prependId="false">   

   <table>

   <tr style="display:block;margin-top:10px;width:100%;margin-left:40%">

   <td style="width:40%">

           <p:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First Name:" style="font-weight:bold" />

        <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{searchManagedBean.firstName}"  required="true" requiredMessage="please enter First Name"> </p:inputText>
        <p:message id="firstNameMsg" for="firstName" showDetail="true"  ></p:message>

    </td>  
    <td style="width: 20%"></td>  
        <td style="width:40%;">
        <p:outputLabel for="lastName" value="Last Name:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
        <p:inputText id="lastName" value="#{searchManagedBean.lastName}" required="true" requiredMessage="please enter Last Name" />
         <p:message id="lastNameMsg" for="lastName" showDetail="true"  ></p:message>
        </td> 
            </tr>
    <tr style="display:block;margin-top:10px;width:100%;margin-left:78%">
    <td  style="width:40%">  <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{searchController.getEmployee(searchManagedBean)}" update="firstNameMsg lastNameMsg emailMsg phoneMsg dataTable"/></td>
                </tr>
         </table>

</h:form>

<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="emp" rendered="#{not empty searchController.employeeList}" value="#{searchController.employeeList}" rowStyleClass="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" resizableColumns="true" resizeMode="expand" scrollWidth="50%" scrollHeight="150" >
    <p:column headerText="First Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.firstName}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Last Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.lastName}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Email">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.email}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Phone">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.phone}"/>
    </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Edit">
       <p:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{searchController.getEditForm(emp)}"  style="margin-left:40px;color:blue;"></p:commandLink>

    </p:column>


</p:dataTable>


</h:body>  

</html>
```

My question is that after entering first name and last name, when I click on submit button it need to hit controller's getEmployee() method and it needs to display data table values from controller's getEmployeeList(). Here eventhough using ViewScoped bean Iam not getting output. Any suggestions??

Comment: Please start by making a [mcve] if you have a prpblem, otherwise post at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ya I have removed some unnecessary code and i have tested before putting it in stackoverflow.

Comment: But it is not a [mcve]. Copy paste the code above in a **new empty** jsf project. Does it work?

Comment: And check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972653/jsf-why-prependid-false-in-a-form

Comment: I got it!! Actually when i click on commandButton it is firing an ajx call. Making ajax="false" solved my issue...

Comment: No, bad solution... it should work with ajax. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367147/use-of-viewscoped-in-jsf-2-0 Did you read my other comment?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link in there.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render